# Email Alerting from Grafana is not working inside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have prometheus and Grafana in a docker-compose file.
I can visualize all the docker container metrics and host metrics in grafana.
But Email alerting is not working. I have configured the smtp configuration in defaults.ini in the Grafana.

Below is the error i'm getting when I used test alert to alert the error to my corporate mail id. SMTP server is a internal server so it can send emails internally inside the corporate.

> 2018-11-02T09:08:11+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification"
>   logger=alerting.notifier id=1 error="gomail: could not send email 1:
>   read tcp 172.20.0.8:42386->10.5.10.160:25: i/o timeout"

Could you tell me why my grafana container cannot send emails. I also tried prometheus alertmanager to send the mails. its not working too.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Grafana cannot access your email server . Could be a DNS or firewall problem.

Comment: Did you open the correct ports from your Docker container. From the log, it should be `:42386`.

Comment: Just expose the port: `docker run [...] -p 42386:42386`

Comment: Now the port has been changed to 49604 and it is showing the same error.. Its randomly assigning the port

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure your computer can reach the SMTP server at "10.5.10.160:25" ?
2. Have you tried pinging the server from inside the grafana container?

Maybe your computer cannot reach that IP.

Maybe can reach the IP but your SMTP server is only open on ports 465 & 587, not 25, and may require some authentication.

```
Just expose the port: docker run [...] -p 42386:42386
```

`tcp 172.20.0.8:42386` is the IP:port where you are calling from; you don't need to expose that, contrary to what *Mornor* said in the comments